Graphics in PUTTING THE "FINANCE" INTO "PUBLIC FINANCE": A THEORY OF CAPITAL GAINS TAXATION
In their NBER Paper with the title above Mark A. Aguiar Benjamin Moll Florian Scheuer display a number of diagrams.
I am interested in learning how they computed Figure 4 and 5.
I was able to derive all equations until this section, but the authors do not provide much detail with which equations and with which methods they produce the diagrams. In particular they do not state which equations they used for computing the diagrams. I think they use differential equations. If so, I would like to understand with which methods they solved the differential equations numerically.
I would grateful for any hints or helpful references.

Your question would benefit from a link, perhaps https://benjaminmoll.com/wp-content/uploads/2024/06/PFPF.pdf
